# Make target containing subdirectory based on target dependencies

Tags: static, makefile, target, rules, substitution

Say I have a list of source files and each are to be compiled to separate binaries:

```
SRCS = abcd.c efgh.c ijkl.c
```

And I want output files in separate subdirectories based on the file names like this:

- build/abcd/abcd
- build/efgh/efgh
- build/ijkl/ijkl

I'm thinking a static pattern rule is the way to go. The pseudo-make-rule can be something like:

```
$(TARGETS): build/%/%: %.c
    # stuff ...
```

I started by making a list of the subdirectories based on the filenames:

```
DIRS = $(SRCS:%.c=build/%)
```

So now we have DIRS = build/abcd build/efgh build/ijkl. I thought I can make the list of targets now with something like:

```
BLDS = $(DIRS:%=%/$(basename %))
```

But of course this doesn't work since the wildcard can not be used multiple times within a pattern. Therefore I'm now stuck at BLDS = build/abcd/% build/efgh/% build/ijkl/%.

Obviously I'm totally going about this the wrong way. How would you go about this?

For now I'm writing each rule explicitly, which is starting to get a bit tedious:

```
compile = # command to do stuff
BD = build

all: $(BD)/abcd/abcd $(BD)/efgh/efgh $(BD)/ijkl/ijkl

$(BD)/abcd/abcd: abcd.c
    $(call compile)

$(BD)/efgh/efgh: efgh.c
    $(call compile)

$(BD)/ijkl/ijkl: ijkl.c
    $(call compile)

clean:
    rm -rf build/*

.PHONY: all
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
SRCS:=abcd.c efgh.c ijkl.c

# We could fold NAMES into BLDS's definition if NAMES is not used elsewhere.
NAMES:=$(SRCS:%.c=%)

BLDS:=$(foreach name,$(NAMES),$(subst foo,$(name),build/foo/foo))

# We don't use DIRS below but the question had this variable.
DIRS:=$(dir $(BLDS))

TARGETS:=$(BLDS)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): $$(notdir $$@).c
    @echo Build $@ from $^
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@
```

There are two important changes. The first is to reorder how the variables are created, and use `subst`, which allows replacing a matched string multiple times. The second is to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) so that make builds rules for each of your targets. You initially a pattern with two `%`, [but the docs say](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html):

> A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target contains the character `%' (*exactly one* of them).

(Emphasis added.)

I've tested the above with fake files `abcd.c` `efgh.c` and `ijkl.c` and get the following output:

```
$ make
Build build/abcd/abcd from abcd.c
mkdir -p build/abcd/
touch build/abcd/abcd
Build build/efgh/efgh from efgh.c
mkdir -p build/efgh/
touch build/efgh/efgh
Build build/ijkl/ijkl from ijkl.c
mkdir -p build/ijkl/
touch build/ijkl/ijkl
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this. I've actually never heard of secondary expansion in make before so this was really enlightening.